# Is there a way to seperate or tokenize sentences from an arraylist and put it in a new arraylist for each senteces?

Tags: java, oop

So for my assignment, given was 3 different sentences.

For example;

1. "The car is white"
2. "The cat is black"
3. "The sky is blue"

These sentences are in an arrayList, named sList

and the question asked to seperate or tokenize each word using delimiter white blank/space and store each work into a new arrayList called wordList.

for the seperating each word, i figured that out by using

```
for(int i = 0; i < sList.size(); i++){
        String sentence = sList.get(i);
        String str[] = sentence.split(" ");
    }
```

but im having problem to store each word into a new arrayList

Comment: What problem are you having with the new array lists, exactly?

Comment: Let's break down the problem. 1st you have different sentences. 2nd - Each sentence is made up of words. 3rd - you need an array equal to the size of cumulative length of each sentence so you have to add up the total words. 4th you have to iterate over each sentence and split it on the basis of blank. 5th - you have to store individual words in the array in pt 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply have to put all the words from these strings into an array named `wordList` then you would first create that list before your `for` loop like this:

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
```

after you have collected your splitted words into `String str[]` you can iterate through it and add word by word into `wordList` like this:

```
String str[] = sentence.split(" ");
for(String word : str) {
    wordList.add(word);
}
```

So to wrap it up your code should look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
sList.add("The car is white");
sList.add("The cat is black");
sList.add("The sky is blue");

ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < sList.size(); i++){
    String sentence = sList.get(i);
    String str[] = sentence.split(" ");
    for(String word : str) {
        wordList.add(word);
    }
}
```

If you print `wordList` you will get:

```
[The, car, is, white, The, cat, is, black, The, sky, is, blue]
```

Comment: Ouh i see, so in my the coding I actually have already collected the words in String str[] = sentence.split[]; ? And the for loop is to insert the words into the arraylist. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AshreefulAmni Yes, `str[]` is an array with sentences from `sList` splitted up. If you put `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));` under the  `String str[] = sentence.split(" ");` you can print those arrays and see that you get an array `[The, car, is, white]`,  `[The, cat, is, black]` etc.